# how to simplify scalar product of 2 scalar triple products.

Tags: vectors

Can anyone explain to me how to simplify following expression (a scalar product of two scalar triple products),
$$(a\cdot(b \times c))( p\cdot(q\times r))
\quad\quad ( \text{ or }\;\; [a,b,c][p,q,r]\;),
$$
where $\times$ is cross product, $\cdot$ is dot product and $a,b,c,p,q,r$ are vectors.

Comment: You might want to use latex coding

Comment: can you explain me about it!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rsoj2YavveE
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DvDO1mea1w0
http://www.forkosh.com/mimetextutorial.html

Comment: aren't there any other method to do that. because i was not taught about latex coding but that was asked in our exam.

Comment: Is the red $\color{red}{\times}$ in $a.(b \times c) \color{red}{\times} p.(q\times r)$ a cross product???

Comment: no that indicates only multiplication

Comment: @Anj okay, I edited your post to reflect that. The only algebraic identity I know about this is

$$(a \cdot ( b \times c)) (p \cdot ( q \times r)) =
\left|\begin{matrix}
a\cdot p & a \cdot q & a \cdot r\\
b\cdot p & b \cdot q & b \cdot r\\
c\cdot p & c \cdot q & c \cdot r
\end{matrix}
\right|$$ I'm not sure whether this is useful to you or not.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too long for a comment/ not informative enough for an answer, but I think it may help:

Let $\vec{a}=u_a\hat{i}+v_a\hat{j}+w_a\hat{k}$, $\vec{b}=u_b\hat{i}+v_b\hat{j}+w_b\hat{k}$, etc.

Then

\begin{align}
(a\cdot(b \times c))( p\cdot(q\times r))&=
        \begin{vmatrix}
        u_a & v_a & w_a \\
        u_b & v_b & w_b \\
        u_c & v_c & w_c \\
        \end{vmatrix}\cdot \begin{vmatrix}
        u_p & v_p & w_p \\
        u_q & v_q & w_q \\
        u_r & v_r & w_r \\
        \end{vmatrix}
\end{align}